Synonym or "scientific term (jargon)" for "first, second, ... in queue"
Are there notions (preferably scientific (jargon), from whichever discipline) that, ideally, describe in one word the concept of "the first (or second, ...) in line/queue/sequence" or in a related meaning "the immediately next event to arrive/happen" and "the one that follows this event" out of all the possible events that could happen?
First or second in queue, e.g., fit the meaning nicely but are "wordy". Are there better, more concise versions?
Example sentences:

"In the particle accelerator experiment, the proton currently
"firstInQueue" will collide with the target first, while the proton
"secondInQueue" will follow immediately after, ensuring minimal delay
between successive collisions."
"In a single-server queue, the customer firstInQueue is currently
being served, while the customer secondInQueue will enter service as
soon as the server becomes available."


What science deals with queues?

I guess the question rather is: which science doesn't. But one example would be "maths": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory

@TimR Statistics and computer programming are a couple of candidates

Math isn't science. Nor is programming.

For word requests, please give an example sentence showing how the word you're thinking of would fit in. For instance, I suspect the word "subsequent" might be what you're looking for, but it wouldn't fit all contexts.

I’m voting to close this question unless edited to provide a sample sentence

"the concept of the first (or second) in line/in queue" isn't clear at all. Are you referring to the idea of queueing itself? or sequentiality?

What's wrong with "first" or "first place"? What are you trying to talk about, the object, its place, its status as being first, or what? Primariness is in dictionaries but I don't seriously recommend you use it.

@TimR I would dispute both your claims. Mathematics is frequently described as "The Queen of Sciences" and there are plenty of university degree courses in "Computer Science". But this is way off topic and I respectfully suggest we drop it.

@TimR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_science And there is even a nice quote in this article: "One reason why mathematics enjoys special esteem, above all other sciences, is that its laws are absolutely certain and indisputable, while those of other sciences are to some extent debatable and in constant danger of being overthrown by newly discovered facts." (Albert Einstein, I guess). But I guess dont feed it.

How can any word stand in for first or second. Come on...

@StuartF First and second are great. I am just looking for words that convey the meaning of "firstInTheQueue" or "immediatelyNextToCome" more precisely than just "first" or "second".

@Lambie Head of the queue stands in for first in the queue. Come on.

head of something is not a synonym for first. first and second are used in scientific texts all the time. Anyway, your text is computer jargon, not science.

To be clear (though perhaps not as much as I'd like, given the circumstances), I didn’t come here to listen to arbitrary concepts on what does or does not constitute science.

I think the simple and direct answer that serves your needs best is: As far as I can tell, some common words can serve these needs. Technical writing doesn't always need technical words; everyday words are fine as long as their meaning is clear and precise. Technical words are created for moments when we need a specialized meaning that an everyday word doesn't cover; for instance, we talk casually about "weight" but scientifically about "mass."
I agree that "first" or "second" are problematic here: in a queue for movie tickets, for instance, the "first" customer might simply be the one who bought the very first ticket of the day, not the one currently waiting in front of the window. "Current" might be useful in some contexts, but that could be confusing if we want to talk about, not the customer currently being helped at the window, but the first one waiting their turn in the queue. For some needs, the best way to talk about them might be the same way the ticket-seller would: "next." So for instance, I would render your customer-service example as:

In a single-server queue, at any given moment, there is a current customer being served, while the next customer will be helped as soon as the server becomes available.

But with the protons, all the protons are waiting for an experience they're about to have, so I would probably avoid "current." This context doesn't seem to have any problem with "first" and "second," because the first in the queue is the first overall anyway. I would probably just talk about them simply, as "the first in the queue" (though I suspect very much that it's "queue" that would get a more technical equivalent):

In the particle accelerator experiment, the first proton in the queue will collide with the target first, while the second proton will follow immediately after, ensuring minimal delay between successive collisions.


As a lapsed physicist, I do find the idea of protons being in a queue to be very weird. Particles in accelerators are usually said to be in a beam, but that's for a large number of them. If I were writing about individual collisions, I'd cut out the unnecessary redundancy that the first proton collides first and write something simple like, "In the particle accelerator experiment, the second proton will collide with the target about [X] nanoseconds after the first one." ("Immediately" is also oddly vague for a physics experiment).

@CanadianYankee Yeah, I'm assuming that the example was a bit contrived and fabricated for the need of the question

The first element in a queue is often known as the head of the queue. The last item is the tail.
If it is the next item to be processed then it could be described as pending or even next.
The one behind the head could be the subsequent item, but this also refers to all the other items, it can be both singular or plural.
To a large extent, it depends on context, what type of queue it is. For example if there were a queue of people waiting to be served the server might just call "Next!" although "Next customer please." would be more polite.

I respect the initiative, but in my opinion this question is highly unclear right now and it would be better to wait until edited before answering, so we can offer more targeted answers instead of a grab bag of many loosely related words
